# JavaFX GridPane Incorrect Node Bounds After Setting Column/Row

Tags: java, javafx

When setting new row and column positions of a node contained in a GridPane, the bounds do not update until sometime later (My guess is that JavaFX calculates these at the end of the loop). I was wondering if there was a way to force these bounds to be re-calculated so that `boundsAfter` contains the correct values rather than the same as `boundsPre` (as shown in the output)?.

```
Bounds boundsPre = theNode.localToScene(theNode.getBoundsInLocal());
System.out.println("PRE-MOVE: " + boundsPre);

GridPane.setColumnIndex(theNode, newCol);
GridPane.setRowIndex(theNode, newRow);
// Todo: Force JavaFX to recalculate the bounds here

Bounds boundsAfter = theNode.localToScene(theNode.getBoundsInLocal());
System.out.println("BOUNDS: " + boundsAfter );
```

Output:

```
PRE-MOVE: BoundingBox [minX:25.0, minY:339.0, minZ:0.0, width:243.0, height:116.0, depth:0.0, maxX:268.0, maxY:455.0, maxZ:0.0]
BOUNDS: BoundingBox [minX:25.0, minY:339.0, minZ:0.0, width:243.0, height:116.0, depth:0.0, maxX:268.0, maxY:455.0, maxZ:0.0]
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: Made a mistake in my previous comment. Although it's true `boundsInLocal` should not be affected by changing the row/column indices, unless changing those indices results in a change in size, I didn't realize you were transforming the bounds from local to scene. In that case changing the row/column indices _should_ give you different bounds. However, bounds are typically only calculated during a layout pass. So either observe the `boundsInLocal` property and react when it changes, or call `applyCss()` followed by `layout()` on the root of the scene. The first approach is likely "cleaner".

Comment: @Slaw My software allows users to drag a node from one GridPane cell to another. To accomplish this, it uses the co-ordinates of the node during MouseEvent (drag event). Unfortunately this drag event can fire multiple times before the layout pass occurs which results in the incorrect co-ordinates being used in the move code and therefor results in the node being moved incorrectly. I will attempt to halt further processing of the drag event until a `boundsInLocal` change has been observed so that only correct co-ordinates of the node being moved are used.

Comment: @Slaw I did not see your edit in time, thanks for updating it further. `applyCss();` and `layout();` in place of the comment in my question `// Todo: Force JavaFX to recalculate the bounds here` works perfectly. Would you like to propose this as a solution to the question? Observing `boundsInLocal` property change may also be a solution for others who do not care to update the bounds immediately. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: This just feels a bit like you are using the wrong approach entirely. When I’ve toyed with applications like checker-board games, the approach I use is to put a pane in each grid cell. I add nodes representing pieces to the appropriate pane corresponding to the cell you want it to be in. Then just register drag handlers with the pieces which update `translateX` and `translateY`, and drag drop handlers with the panes which move the dragged piece to the new pane. That avoids getting your hands dirty with the details of the underlying layout entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Call the `layout()` method on the base pane after setting the row or column position. This "*Executes a top-down layout pass on the scene graph under this parent*" according to the Oracle JavaFX Documentation, which results in the bounds to be re-calculated of all child nodes belonging to the pane.

```
Bounds boundsPre = theNode.localToScene(theNode.getBoundsInLocal());
System.out.println("PRE-MOVE: " + boundsPre);

GridPane.setColumnIndex(theNode, newCol);
GridPane.setRowIndex(theNode, newRow);

baseLayout.layout(); // Causes a layout pass which updates the bounds

Bounds boundsAfter = theNode.localToScene(theNode.getBoundsInLocal());
System.out.println("BOUNDS: " + boundsAfter );
```

Output:

```
PRE-MOVE: BoundingBox [minX:25.0, minY:87.0, minZ:0.0, width:243.0, height:116.0, depth:0.0, maxX:268.0, maxY:203.0, maxZ:0.0]
BOUNDS: BoundingBox [minX:25.0, minY:213.0, minZ:0.0, width:243.0, height:116.0, depth:0.0, maxX:268.0, maxY:329.0, maxZ:0.0]
```

**Solution 2**

If you do not care to update the bounds right away, observe the `boundsInLocal` property. This event will fire when JavaFX completes its next layout pass.

```
theNode.boundsInLocalProperty().addListener((observableValue, bounds, updatedBounds) ->
{
    System.out.println("BOUNDS: " + updatedBounds);
});
```

**Credit**

As pointed out by Slaw in the question comments:

> So either observe the boundsInLocal property and react when it changes, or call applyCss() followed by layout() on the root of the scene. The first approach is likely "cleaner"